# Export to CVS: Preventing auto conversion to date

Tags: java, cvs

I some textfield I wish to export to CVS without date conversion..

Example:

"1/1"  is change to 01 Jan 2012 when I open the .cvs file with excel.

The current solution is to add a whitespace, may I know if there is any more elegant solution?

Bonus question: There is a API for exporting data to CVS? I find that setting the column using arrays very crude.

Comment: Here's a "Bonus Question" for you: What have you tried?

Comment: The current solution is to add a whitespace,

Comment: Try to prepend the number with a single quote `"'1/1"`. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Also, a short googling lead to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178145/exporting-to-csv-excel-in-java Why didn't you google first before asking?

Answer (score 0):

This conversion is because of Excel not the CSV file.
There are two solutions

1. Use a library to export xls files
2. Create a new Excel file in Excel and select whole sheet and change the type of cells to Text (or at least those column you think that should not be changed to date). Then you can import your csv file by copy and paste its content into the excel file and split the columns using the import wizard.